# Application to create flash demo of a website

Tags: flash

I'm looking for some software to create a flash demo 'tour' of a website I've created.  FOS would be preferred but commercial is ok so long as not too expensive (I'm probably going to use this just the once).

Ideally something programmable to I can edit the demo and insert text, overlays etc.  I'm also not interested in adding sound.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) for creating flash demo tours of native applications, but it should work as well for websites.

Editing overlays and removing frames is possible, programming it is not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

[SWiSH](http://www.swishzone.com) - Easy Flash Animation Software Tools and Designer Templates

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Captivate](http://tryit.adobe.com/in/captivate/?sdid=EQFZC) is the perfect solution.